# How to duplicate a database in db2 with all the tables and data included?

Tags: db2

I want to duplicate a database with all the data, tables and triggers included.
Eg. i want SAMPLE database to be duplicated to TESTSAMPLE database with all the tables, data and triggers included

Comment: You should add your research and efforts to this question and add where are you stuck?

Comment: i have tried db2 move command but its does not work for me. im trying to duplicate a database with a different name for testing on the same enviroment

Comment: db2move is the command or a redirected backup

Answer (score 0):

You can use db2move or database backup/restore. This answer shows backup/restore.

For small Db2-databases on Windows/Linux/Unix you can take an offline Db2-backup and restore the resulting file into a new database in the same Db2-instance.  Some GUI tools let you do this via a GUI, but I won't describe those.

For more details browse to the free online [Db2 knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001933.html) website.

In the example below I duplicate the sample database into the testsmpl database, both are in the same Db2-instance.

First, close/stop any applications that connect to the sample database, because we want an offline backup.

If your database is *NOT* default, or has non-default tablespaces, or is configured for online backups then the procedure below is not what you want.

For Db2-server running on **Microsoft-Windows**, with default setup, and a single database called sample in the Db2-instance, on the DB2-server run these commands:

ensure your username is a member of local group DB2ADMNS

Start > Run > db2cwadmin.bat

ensure you are in the correct Db2 instance (only if you have multiple Db2 instances, not default).

In the resulting db2cmd.exe window run these commands:

```
db2 force applications all
md %temp%\db2backup
db2 backup database sample to %temp%
db2 restore database sample from %temp%\db2backup  into testsmpl
```

For **Unix/Linux, with a single sample database in the Db2 instance**:

Open a terminal window to the Db2 server

become the correct Db2 instance owner via su or sudo (example su - db2inst1 )

```
db2 force applications all
mkdir -p /tmp/db2backup
db2 force applications all
db2 backup database sample to /tmp/db2backup
db2 restore database sample from /tmp/db2backup into testsmpl
```